# Error Running ADB Command while running MobSF dynamic analysis

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, dynamic-analysis, mobsf

I am trying to run MobSF dynamic analysis.
Using Android Studio Emulator created a device with Android 9.0, API 28

Set Path in Environment variable - C:\Users\91901\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator

Set ADB_BINARY path in C:\MobSF\mobsf\MobSF\settings.py

```
ADB_BINARY = os.getenv('MOBSF_ADB_BINARY', 'C:\\Users\\91901\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe')
```

Run AVD before starting MobSF using emulator command line options.

```
$ emulator -avd Pixel_6_Pro_Android_9_API_28 -writable-system -no-snapshot
```

Now when I open the MobSF dynamic analysis:

```
http://localhost:8000/android/dynamic_analysis/
```

Getting the below Error:

```
[INFO] 29/Feb/2024 23:54:54 - OS Environment: Windows Windows-10-10.0.22631-SP0
[INFO] 29/Feb/2024 23:54:54 - MobSF Basic Environment Check
[INFO] 29/Feb/2024 23:54:54 - Checking for Update.
[INFO] 29/Feb/2024 23:54:55 - No updates available.
[INFO] 29/Feb/2024 23:55:20 - Connecting to Android /home/mobsf/.MobSF/config.py
[INFO] 29/Feb/2024 23:55:20 - Waiting for 2 seconds...
[ERROR] 29/Feb/2024 23:55:22 - Error Running ADB Command
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MobSF\mobsf\DynamicAnalyzer\views\android\environment.py", line 167, in adb_command
    result = subprocess.check_output(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91901\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91901\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\91901\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe', '-s', '/home/mobsf/.MobSF/config.py', 'shell', 'getprop', 'ro.build.version.release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: MobSF was developed for Linux, thus it uses paths like `/home/mobsf/.MobSF/config.py` that most likely don't exist in your Windows system.

Comment: The adb command is malformed, there's a filename after `-s`